# DataOutputStream nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on a `DataOutputStream` in Android.

I first wrote some code to write out files in Java using `DataOutputStream`. Everything worked perfectly. The I imported the code to an Android project and I am getting some weird behavior.

The only code I changed to be android specific is how I get the directory.

So what exactly is happening is: I am creating the `DataOutputStream` and then I am closing it. That is all for now. I figure it is a good first step to test if stream was opened correctly is to close it.

`DataOutputStream` is a class instance variable.

When I call close on it in same method it closes fine. When I call close on it from a different method, it gets `NullPointerException`. But doing these same things in Java did not cause a problem, though they did in Android.

```
public class WavFileOutStream {

    private DataOutputStream stream;

    public WavFileOutStream(String fileName)
    {

        // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory. 
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES), fileName);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("trace", "Directory not created");
        }

        try {
            stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

            if(stream==null)
            {
                Log.i("trace","Null Stream!");
            }

            //<--PROBLEM LINE 1-->
            //If I call close from this line I get NO nullPointer
            //stream.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        //<--PROBLEM LINE 1-->
        //If I call close from this line I get a nullPointer
        //I comment out other close() first
        close();

    }

    public void close()
    {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539): Process: com.example.ringtonegenerator, PID: 11539
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ringtonegenerator/com.example.ringtonegenerator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at com.example.ringtonegenerator.WavFileOutStream.close(WavFileOutStream.java:178)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at com.example.ringtonegenerator.WavFileOutStream.<init>(WavFileOutStream.java:43)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at com.example.ringtonegenerator.WavFileWriter.writeWave(WavFileWriter.java:10)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at com.example.ringtonegenerator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-24 12:49:39.229: E/AndroidRuntime(11539):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you show your logcat trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you throw an exception when the stream is created, the stream will still be null and you will still call close. There is no check for null there, so it will throw NPE.

```
public void close()
{
    if(stream != null){
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. There is no check for null in either case.

Comment: That's correct. But it is possible along the exception path for it to be null; therefore, it will throw an exception in that condition. You need to null check it in close:

Answer (score 0):

You have code after a catch block that should be inside the try block. That's why you get the NPE.

The underlying problem is that you are calling file.mkdirs() when you should be calling file.getParentFile().mkdirs(), so you are creating the target file as a directory, so you can't create the target file, so you are getting an IOException instead of creating the FileOutputStream, so the DataOutputStream reference is still null, so you get an NPE when the code after the catch block, that should be in the try block, executes.

NB the result of 'new' cannot be null, so testing it straight afterwards is futile.

Comment: Why should the code after the catch block be inside of it? It calls another method that ha a try catch in it and it worked perfectly in java, this is not the problem.

I will try using file.getParentFile().mkdirs(). I just went by the exact code specified in the android reference docs to do exactly this.

Comment: Because that way you can't get the NPE. As I said in my answer.

Comment: I changed to file.getParentFile().mkdirs() and I still get NPE and directory is not created.

Comment: So what happened when you moved the code after the catch block that should be in the try block into the try block?

Comment: No null pointer. In the end though I wanted to check for null pointer so I could tell if file was opened properly and it seems it is not being opened properly. I followed the code directly from android docs and I added what you suggested and file is not being opened. I have proper permissions added.

Comment: So you can't create the directory, so you can't create the file either, so you get an exception instead, so the code that is in the wrong place throws an NPE. If your code was correctly structured you wouldn't get the NPE. If you want to use null as a signal that you didn't create the file, you have to *test* for it, and you aren't doing that either. But why you would want to do that when you already have a try/catch structure that does the same thing is a mystery. Is there some problem with writing code that cannot fail?

Comment: I am not writing final code here. I am just quickly testing "did the file open". It is not opened. Forget the NPE now, it served it purpose. Its done. Now I am figuring out why file will not open.

Comment: 'Not writing final code' isn't any kind of an excuse for writing incorrect code. If you had structured the try/catch properly in the first place you wouldn't have had this problem.